# How is DeckGL's performance for visualizing massive point cloud data?

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl2, deck.gl

What has been your experience with using DeckGL for visualization large point clouds?

I am new to WebGL generally and am assessing frameworks/approaches to use for visualizing a massive amount of point cloud data.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions or similar are off topic for stack overflow. Maybe someone else can suggest a dev discussion site where this would be more appropriate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a cursory glance at the library, but it looks very performant. With point visualization there is pretty much one fast path to doing it on the GPU and it looks like deck.gl is utilizing it well.

For instance:

https://deck.gl/#/examples/core-layers/point-cloud-layer

800k points.. and runs well for me.